# WiX toolset EXE Wrapper installer with no files

Tags: wix, installation, exe, wrapper

I have a simple working EXE wrapper in WIX but I don't like that I have to add at least one file for it to work and I can't seem to find a way to not add files to it, is it even possible?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product>
    <Package Compressed="yes" InstallerVersion="301" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="MyInstaller">
          <Single unwanted dummy component here>
        </Directory </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Binary Id="MYEXE" SourceFile="Installer.exe" />
      <CustomAction Id="RunInstaller" BinaryKey="MYEXE" ExeCommand="" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncNoWait" />
      <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="RunInstaller" Before="InstallFinalize">
          NOT Installed
        </Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Level="1">
        <Single unwanted dummy component ref here>
      </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to have atleast one file (although the scenarios where you don't have any files are very, very rare)   you do have to have atleast 1 component and that component has to have a key.  The key can be a file, registry entry or by default directory.

The old saying is that installers is *more* then just copying files but generally they always include atleast copying a file or two.